# Do I have to send multiple requests one by one to get all nodes?

Tags: graphql

I'm fairly new to graphql, and met this problem when exploring GitHub's [graphql API](https://developer.github.com/v4/).

Say I'm fetching all followers of a user. Schema is roughly this:

```
query($after:String!) { 
  user(login: "laike9m") {
    followers(first: 100, after: $after) {
      nodes {
        name
      }
      pageInfo {
        hasNextPage
        endCursor
      }
    }
  }
}
variables {
   "after": "1234"
}
```

If there are 600 followers, does it mean I have to send 6 requests to get them all(`first` has the limit of 100)? And it seems there's no way to parallelize it, since end cursor is needed to perform the next request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The only way you can do is iterating with endCursor and hasNextPage values. 
If hasNextPage is false you can terminate the iteration.
Like REST API, we can't programmatically write this.